# Интеграция программы с штрих сканером

Tags: железо

Недавно появилсь задача  создать программу которая с помощью штрих-сканера будет получать номера штрих-кода, после обрабатывать и складывать в БД.

Больше всего интересует вопрос о том как привязать штрих-сканер к программы.
Как бы вы посоветовали это реализовать? На каком языке?

Программу планируется писать под платформу Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большинство штрих-код сканеров выглядят в системе как обычное устройство ввода. Т.е. HID. А по сути эмулируют клавиатуру. Т.о. никаких специальных действий производить не нужно. Просто используйте в программе стандартные компоненты ввода текстовой информации. Например, TEdit. Если же требуется, чтобы программа автоматически перескакивала при вводе информации с одного текстового поля на другое, то, возможно, имеет смысл настроить сам сканер штрих-кодов так, чтобы он вводил некие управляющие символы по окончании считывания очередного штрих-кода. Для этого очень рекомендуется ознакомиться с руководством по его эксплуатации.